# TYPO3 QueryRepository returns empty and can not use it as condition

Tags: php, repository, typo3

I have created a query on my repository file which searches for objects with specific values. For example:

```
/**
     * @param int $uid
     * @param string $value
     * @param int $someIntValue
     *
     * @return array|\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface
     */
    public function findByFields($uid, $value, $someIntValue)
    {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
        $query->matching(
            $query->logicalAnd(
                [
                    $query->equals('some_field', $uid),
                    $query->equals('value', $value),
                    $query->equals('some_other_field', $someIntValue)
                ])
        );
        return $query->execute();
```

Now this gives me an empty object which is fine because i don't have anyhting in the database which meets the requirements.

But if i want to add a condition which evaluates if the object is empty it does not work.

**Code in my Task**

```
$getObjects = $someRepository->findByFields($oldObject->getUid(), $oldObject->getValue, $oldObject->getExternalValue);

if(empty($getObjects))
{
    // do something
}
else 
{
    // do something else
}
```

Here fails to evaluate the object as empty because it is not actually empty. If i typecast it to an array: (Just to see what is inside)

```
$typecasted = (array)$getObjects;
```

It gives me back what exists in the "empty" object. (with var_dump)

```
*dataMapper => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper singleton object filtered
*persistenceManager => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager singleton object filtered
*numberOfResults => NULL
*query => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query prototype object
*queryResult => NULL
```

**The question:**

How do i get the condition to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found the solution.**

If nothing found TYPO3 returns the query. All i had to do is the following:

```
if($query->execute()->count())
{
   return $query->execute();
}
else 
{
   return NULL;
}
```

What this does, it to evaluate if there are any objects available. If yes then it gives back the objects. If not, it sets the result to NULL and with that the condition can be used.

**EDIT :**

The above works but after @Mathias Brodala 's recommendation, i tried something like that as well.

```
if (count($getObjects) > 0)
{
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump('exists');
} else {
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump('does not exist');
}
```

Both ways work. Take your pick.

Thanks  @Mathias Brodala

Comment: Alternatively you can just use `count($getObjects)` or use `$getObjects->toArray()`. A simple cast to array never works for anything aside scalar values.

Comment: the luck of experience didnt let me think of that, Thanks!